# What title did Qing China use for US presidents?

Tags: history, terminology, terms-of-address

What title did Qing China use for the US president, given that US presidents are periodically "deposed"? Certainly not 王 as the office is not hereditary and could not be held for life.

I am looking for translations used by the Qing government, and also other translations used by writers of the era (in literature, newspapers, correspondence, etc).

Answer (score 6):

Formally, the Chinese title was *President* - that is, the English word *President* was transliterated into Chinese as **伯理璽天德**. From the [Treaty of Wanghia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Wanghia) (望廈條約):

> 以上關涉太平、和好、貿易、海面各款條約，應候各大臣奏明大清大皇帝批准，大合眾國大**伯理璽天德**既得各國選舉國會長公會大臣議定允肯批准...
>
> *The present Treaty of peace, amity, and commerce, shall be ratified and approved by the **President** of the United States, by and with the advice and consent of the Senate thereof, and by the August Sovereign of the Ta Tsing Empire...*

Comment: Are you aware of other titles? I vaguely remember having read that there were a dozen or so different titles that had been used to refer to US presidents in literature, newspapers, etc.

Comment: @Flux I can't find any. There is 伯理, which is just the first two characters of 伯理璽天德, then there is the word 總統(領), which is really just the modern word - these were used in less formal contexts during the Qing.

Comment: What language would this have been? It certainly doesn’t sound like persistent in msm. I mean, probably some form of 官话 but still...?

Comment: @user3306356 you mean *President*? bo-li-xi-ten-de has all the necessary consonants to approximate *president* (b l x t d > p r s d t). You're right though, Qing Dynasty is slightly different from MSM.

Answer (score 3):

depends on the original texts, here’re some:

in [瀛環志略 卷九](https://archive.org/details/02087088.cn/page/n86/mode/1up)

governor of state is “統領”, while president of the united states is “總統領“ (i suspected it’s the origin of “總統”

[image]

in 合省國說，the president is just “統領”

in 遐邇貫珍，governor of state is “總憲”, while president of the united states is “合郡國主“

[image]

in 海國圖說 卷五十九：

governor of state is “首領”, while president of the united states is “統領”

[image]

there should be more, have fun :)